# Absolute value property (proof)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, absolute-value

I want to prove
$$
\lvert a \rvert \geq b \iff a\leq-b \quad \text{ or } \quad a\geq b,
$$
for $b>0$.

Case 1: $a>0$, $\lvert a \rvert=a$  so $$
a\geq b
$$

Case 2: $a=0$, $\lvert a \rvert=0$ so
$$
0\geq b, \quad \textbf{not possible because }\mathbf{b>0?} 
$$
Case 3. $a<0$, $\lvert a \rvert =-a$ so
$$
-a\geq b
$$

Summary:

$a>0: a\geq b \iff a-b\geq 0$
$a<0: -a\geq b \iff b+a\leq 0$

This gives 
\begin{align}
b+a&\leq 0 \leq a-b &\iff \\
b+a &\leq a-b &\iff \\
2b &\leq 0 &\iff \\
b &\leq 0 \quad \textbf{What?}
\end{align}

**Questions:**

Why is case 2 a contradiction?

Why can I not combine the inequalities (final step?

Comment: You can't combine the inequalities because $a$ can't be *both* positive and negative, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer each of your questions in turn.$\newcommand{\OR}{\ \ {\rm{\small{OR}}}\ \ }$

In case 2, you've discovered that the left-hand side of the equivalency (that is, the statement $|a| \geq b$) implies a contradiction if $a$ is assumed to be zero and $b$ is supposed to be positive. This means that the left-hand statement is false (when $a=0$), but this doesn't mean that your *entire* statement-to-be-proved is false, because you are trying to prove an *equivalency*, not just one particular statement that's *part* of the equivalency. Remember, to say "$p \iff q$" is to say that the statements $p$ and $q$ have the same truth value: are either both true or both false. "$|a| \geq b$" may be false for $a = 0$, but so is the statement "$a \leq -b \OR a \geq b$" because with $a=0$ both of these also imply $b \leq 0$. Lies are equivalent to lies, and hence your *entire* equivalency is *true* for $a = 0$.

As for your second question, you can't combine the inequalities in the way you did. As Bernard pointed out, the two inequalities you combine come from different cases: $a-b \geq 0$ if $a>0$, and $b+a \leq 0$ if $a<0$. Therefore you can't assume that the two inequalities are *both* true *at the same time* which is necessary before you can combine them. It turns out that whenever one inequality is true, the other one *must* be false. Hence you can never combine them in *any* situation.

But even if you *could* combine those inequalities, I don't think it would lead anywhere useful. Once you've got your three previous cases finished, I would then attempt to prove the converse by assuming first that $a \leq -b$ and proving that must mean $|a| \geq b$, and then independently assuming $a \geq b$ and then proving $|a| \geq b$. Once you do that (and complete the proofs for your original case 2 and case 3), you will have completed the proof of
$$ |a| \geq b \iff a \leq -b \OR a \geq b $$